# Which PayPal SDK is best for me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building an MVC 5 site.
There are multiple vendors with their own product pages
The purchaser is your average consumer. (They may need to setup a PayPal account)

I need to accept payments using PayPal, Visa, etc...
I need to send funds to the respected vendor once their product has been purchased.

Question: What is the best SDK to start with?
There are several different options and I was hoping not to have to go down a road that wasn't necessary

thank you

Comment: This is not a question where you will find a correct answer... it depends what you prefer and how you would like to handle the purchase mechanism. The easiest (and in my opinion the most secure, also for the feeling of the enduser) is to send all non critical information to PayPal directly and handle the complete paying process on paypal and redirect back to your page at the end.

Comment: I agree.  Just wanted to hear the good and bad in hopes to save some heartache. I also agree with your suggested approach  I grabbed Adaptive payments and Adaptive accounts from github. This seemed to be the two that would allow me to achieve what you suggest.  Do you agree?

Comment: I do, keep im mind SO is no discussion platform there are other places for this

Comment: Thank you. Not sure what you mean by is no discussion platform, but I appreciate you sharing your experience.